# korn shell assigning files names to an array

Tags: linux, shell

I am confused with the Korn shell syntax. I need to read all the files of the current directory and assign them to an array. However. I need to exclude directories. The code below includes directories too, which I don't want. Plus I could not get the file names to be assigned to my array.

```
fileCount=0
for fileName in ./*
do
    echo -n 'file = '; echo $fileName
    #$fileNameArr[$fileCount] = $fileName #how do I do this?
    let fileCount+=1
done
```

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in ksh, no loop just one line:

```
set -A filenameArr  ./*
```

However the number of elements in an array are limited - see your ksh man page for your version of ksh.

The version I used on HPUX 10 had 1024, some other versions may have 4096.  Check first, ksh is not bash with essentially unlimited numbers of elements.

The number of filenames you store in the array is:  `echo ${#filenameArr[*]}`

Comment: Ok, but this is also including all the directories. Is there a mask to include the files only?